# Cannot connect to the MongoDB at localhost:3001

Tags: mongodb

I'm using Robo3t and my interface and I am currently connected to other local databases without a problem. However, I'm trying to connect to `Cannot connect to the MongoDB at localhost:3001.`

```
Error:
The network is unreachable. Reason: couldn't connect to server localhost:3001, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to localhost:3001 (127.0.0.1:3001) :: caused by :: Connection refused
```

I don't get it. I never have to access my mongo from my console.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Could you share some more information... What command are you using?

Comment: I'm not using a command, I'm simply connecting to it on Robo3T.

Comment: 3001 is not a standard MongoDB port. Are you sure your connection settings are correct?

Comment: I haven't changed anything :/ it just stopped and it is a mongo DB.